# Cauchy's Problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, cauchy-problem

While reading the Cauchy's problem I have some following doubts:

1. The number of the solutions of Cauchy's problem can be finite?
2. What is the necessary condition for the unique solution?

Comment: Look up Picard's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: For first order partial differential equations?

Comment: This is why context is important. You did not add specifics to your question. People use wrong tags all the time.